# How to tell when user interacts with iOS location-aware lock screen app icon

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, location, location-services

My app uses location services in the background and as a result it shows on the iOS 8 lock screen (see picture). Is there any way to tell when an app is brought to the foreground by the user sliding this button?

The app will necessarily be launched when this button appears -- since it's being awakened by the same location signal that is causing it to appear on the lock screen. Accordingly, `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` has a launch options dict with `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey = 1`.

That's useful, but what I want to know is when the app is **brought to the foreground due to interaction with the button**. No relevant application delegate methods seem to be called in this case, except `didBecomeActive:` and `didMoveToForeground:` but these methods don't carry extra data.
[image]

Comment: Very long time since the question was asked, but I just wonder if you were able to debug this "location awareness"? Since iOS8 our app is getting a very high bounce rate which we think is because of this, but does anyone know if the app starts in background as soon as the app icon shows up at the lock screen?